# The default field selection in a Content Elements variable in Low Variables keeps self-replicating

Tags: low-variables, bug, content-elements

(EE 2.9.2, Low Vars 2.5.0, and Content Elements 1.7.0)

I've created a variable in Low Vars (LV) and made it a Content Elements (CE) type. By default (and understandably yet still annoyingly, I might add), CE displays all possible field types it can handle in new variables: Code, Gallery, Heading, Rich Text, etc. So I go about the usual routine of deleting them all to clear the board for my own custom-named fields, including things like "Image (full width)", "Image (on left)", "Image (on right)", etc.

I then click on the "Save Changes" button, and it loads up the screen where I can begin to add the different CE types as I please and populate them with content... except after all the custom fields I created, I see all the default fields as if they had never been deleted... O.o

Going back in to the CE var's settings, I do indeed see my fields followed by all the default fields. Leaving things as-is and clicking "Save Changes" results in 3 sets of fields to select from - my custom ones, and then *2 sets* of the default CE fields. o.O

So each time I save the CE variable, it re-adds the default set of fields. :-/

I might add that the process of saving changes and/or loading the page after that takes an inordinately long time - 45-60 seconds or so. The rest of the EE backend typically responds in a couple of seconds. >.<

Any ideas?

Comment: This is an issue with Content Elements. Low Variables just provides an API which CE uses for its fieldtype. CE needs to cater for the differences between context; not something LV can (or should) do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then click on the "Save Changes" button, and it loads up the screen
>   where I can begin to add the different CE types as I please and
>   populate them with content... except after all the custom fields I
>   created, I see all the default fields as if they had never been
>   deleted... O.o

Today has been released new version of Content Elements and this bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks - that did indeed fix the backend issue. :) How does it work in the frontend? best I can come up with is using the `{exp:low_variables:pair var="var_name"}` tag pair, with the typical content elements tags inside that. But when I do that, I get a bunch of these errors:"A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Content_Elements_ft::$row

Filename: content_elements/ft.content_elements.php

Line Number: 1094".